# QT:QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory does not work properly

Tags: c++, qt

```
QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Select Directory"), 
            getenv("HOME"), QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks).toStdString(
```

в терминале я имею

> QObject::connect: invalid null parameter

почему кто может помочь понять

Comment: в терминале я имею  QObject::connect: invalid null parameter почему кто может помочь понять

Comment: Что за ОС и окружение?

Comment: CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

Comment: KDE, Gnome, Xfce?

Comment: можно ли как то обойти данную проблему

Answer (score 1):

Это похоже на [баг в Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53686). И, судя по всему, никакого обходного пути нет. Попробуйте отписать в Qt JIRA. Ваш голос и комментарий может помочь разработчиками исправить эту проблему быстрее.

Comment: спасибо вам за все